# Tagging photos using facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, photo, tagging

I have been trying since a long time to tag the photos in facebook albums and to tag the photos being uploaded using the Facebook C# SDK. But I could find a way..

Is it currently possible with Facebook C# SDK V 5 ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily Facebook have just added the ability to tag photos using the graph api which is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).

Just use `FacebookWebClient` to POST to `"PHOTO_ID/tags"`.

Comment: Thanks el_tone.. I was looking for the same.. Although the logic to pass the tagging co-ordinates seems to very criptic, I hope in some way or the other, I can tag the photos...